# How to force webpack to put the plain CSS code into HTML head's style tag?

Tags: html, css, webpack, sass

I have this `webpack.config`:

```
const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackInlineStylePlugin = require('html-webpack-inline-style-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: {
    main: [
      './src/scss/main.scss'
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '',
    filename: 'js/[name].js'
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new UglifyJsPlugin({
        cache: true,
        parallel: true,
        sourceMap: true
      })
    ]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ]
      },
      // ... other stuffs for images
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/main.html',
      filename: 'main.html'
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackInlineStylePlugin()
  ]
};
```

I tried this configuration, but this isn't working well, because the CSS code is generated into the main.css file.

But if I write the CSS code directly into the `<head>` tag as a `<style>`, it's working.

How can I set up the webpack to put the `CSS` code from `Sass` files into the `HTML` as inline CSS?

Or is there a tick to put the CSS first into the `<head>` and after this the `html-webpack-inline-style-plugin` plugin can parse it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've done this before only using [style-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader#singletonstyletag) that by default will add your css as style inline at `<head>` tag. This won't generate any output css file, this just will create one/multiple style tags with all you styles.

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  //... your config

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,  /** or /\.css$/i if you aren't using sass */
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader',
            options: { 
                insert: 'head', // insert style tag inside of <head>
                injectType: 'singletonStyleTag' // this is for wrap all your style in just one style tag
            },
          },
          "css-loader",
          "sass-loader"
        ],
      },
    ]
  },

  //... rest of your config
};
```

**index.js** (*entry point script*)

```
import './css/styles.css';
```

Comment: Any chance you could throw together a gist showing a complete example? I've included your recommended logic in my config with minor modifications (I'm trying to inline vanilla css links in HTML rather than scss files) and while I get no errors, the config seems to ignore my css.

Comment: @AlexanderTsepkov This only will work if you import a main.css in your main.js (`import style from './file.css';`) or if you have the style entry as the question did it.
Like following example https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader#usage check it out. Also, if you share me a link where I can see your code, I can help you and update my awnser if something new is required.