# CSS-In-JS in React or merging the styling inside the JavaScript

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

In a React app, we usually import CSS files into the JavaScript components.
I thought this way we inject the CSS into the final JavaScript build.

However, it seems that React (at least `create-react-app`) still generates separate CSS files.

Why is that?
Is there any way to force CSS stylings to be part of the final **r**? Kind of CSS-In-JS?

Answer (score 0):

You should eject the create-react-app and change webpack config file (style-loader [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53653652/how-to-force-webpack-to-put-the-plain-css-code-into-html-heads-style-tag)) to not create separate file for css bundle or use [html-inline-css-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-inline-css-webpack-plugin).