# Tailwind PostCSS inject styles inline instead of generating a CSS file

Tags: css, pug, tailwind-css, postcss

I am using *PUG* + *Tailwind* + *PostCSS* for a static, single page HTML file which is generated using basic *NPM scripts* (shown below)

I would like the final HTML to have the tailwind styles inlined directly in the `index.html` page, instead of being generated as a `.css` file which is them referenced in the `index.html` file.

### Instead of using an external file:

```
link(rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css")
```

### I *want* this:

```
<style>
  // all my (tailwind) CSS here
</style>
```

Obviously the injection has to happen after *Pug* has compiled *and* also tailwind has been compiled.

**My question is, is there a *Tailwind* plugin or is a *PostCSS-cli* plugin/setting?**

I have been searching for a few hours without luck.

#### Here's my NPM scripts:

```sh
"start": "npm run build && npm run css",
"build": "pug -O src/data/index.js -P -w src/html/index.pug -o dist",
"css": "postcss -o ./dist/styles.css ./src/css/*.css --watch",
```

Comment: I'm curious, did you get any answer ?

Comment: @AirOne - I haven't

Comment: @vsync if you're interested in Rollup, I can post for you a solution I ended up with, isn't really great but you get the css statically bundled in.

Answer (score 0):

You could always disable the css "cleaning", compile your css independently of the pug and link them together with webpack.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53653652/how-to-force-webpack-to-put-the-plain-css-code-into-html-heads-style-tag) and [this webpack plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-pug-plugin).

Hope it helps, for once. At least it would work.

Comment: Why do you assume I use Webpack? This isn't a webapp.. it's a super overkill for my  need.

Comment: @vsync, to be honest, I ended up writing a hook in Rollup which replaces a string with the static css in my bundle. you can force postcss to generate the static css using `export: true`.

Comment: btw, despite this answer doesn't really help so much, it's still unrelated to postcss or pug.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply inject the css file into your html after any build commands, with a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# inject_css.sh

cp index.html output.html

echo "<style>" >> output.html
cat dist/styles.css >> output.html
echo "</style>" >> output.html
```

Then, add this script after your build rules in your NPM script like so:

```
"start": "npm run build && npm run css && ./inject_css.sh"
```

`>>` Appends text to a file. In this case, we're adding an opening style tag, then concatenating output.css, then finally, closing the style tag and you should have all your compiled css code directly inside a style tag in your HTML.

Comment: Yes, I've already resorted to that :) I only use Windows OS, so am using another NPM package to inject

Answer (score 0):

##### You could go with using [Play CDN](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/play-cdn)

> Use the Play CDN to try Tailwind right in the browser without any build step. The Play CDN is designed for development purposes only, and is not the best choice for production.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>  Inject it here
</head>
<body>
  <h1 class="text-3xl font-bold underline">  
    Hello world!
  </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not best choice at all, it's a rather bad one I would say because this is only for playground and not real projects

Comment: @vsync as far as i have understood your question. It states you want inline style without any creation of the css file. This is your go , to use cdn ‍♀️

Comment: Well, I want that for the purpose of NOT having to have an HTTTP request to get the CSS file, and you simply replaces a CSS request call, which is local, to a third-party script, which is worse now in terms of performance. Such inline-injection **must** happen during the build process, so the output will be clean of any HTTP requests

Comment: My bad I wasn't knowing you wanted to avoid http request, if thats your use case, this is not the choice, apologies